# How to reset a command block's status?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'd like to use a [comparator](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_comparator)  to act when e.g. a `testforblock` [command block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block) attached to a button triggers. But the comparator changes its state only when the button is pressed after the test result changes, while I'd like to have a short pulse if nothing changed, i.e.

```
previous command block state | new command block state | desired output
           on                |           off           |      off
           off               |           on            |      on
           on                |           on            |      briefly off, then on
           off               |           off           |      briefly on, then off
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You're committing the cardinal sin of mixing command blocks and redstone.  I'm sure there's a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this contraption:

[image: Please accept this answer if you want to.]

It will work exactly as you described.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making a machine, just set up another command block coming out of the comparator with this command:

```
/blockdata <Insert Coords> {SuccessCount:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is actually sufficient that an on-signal is reset after a short while, which can be simply achieved by splitting the input signal and additionally feeding it to the comparator's side.

Comment: @QbsidianH20 Originally I intended to test the other answers first, but I never came around to do so, so I guess your suggestion is appropriate...